# Selecionar todos os JCheckboxes ao clicar em botão

Tags: java, swing

Minha aplicação tem uma lista de `JCheckBox` dentro de um `Box`. Quero fazer um botão para marcar todos eles, mas meu código está dando o seguinte erro quando clico no botão

> "java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: java.awt.Component.setSelected"

Fiz um exemplo de interface gráfica no netbeans.

Segue código:

```
package NewClass;

import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    Box box = Box.createVerticalBox();
    public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents();
        for(int i=0 ; i<13 ; i++){
            box.add( new JCheckBox(Integer.toString(i)));
            box.getComponent(i).setName(Integer.toString(i));
        }
        Box box2 = Box.createHorizontalBox();
        box2.setBounds(10,10,60,200);
        box2.add(new JScrollPane(box));
        // Adciona Box Externo na janela
        this.add(box2);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jButton1.setText("marcar tudo");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(129, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addContainerGap(181, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        for(int i=0 ; i<box.getComponentCount() ; i++){
           box.getComponent(i).setSelected(true);
        }
    }                                        

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        //</editor-fold>
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Há dois erros no código:

1- O container do tipo `Box` não retorna um `JCheckBox`, ele retorna o tipo mais genérico `Component`, que é a classe da qual todos os componentes da API swing herdam. Logo, você não pode invocar o método `setSelected()` pois a classe citada nem possui este método, já que ele é herdado de componentes que são subtipos de [`AbstractButton`](http://www.enseignement.polytechnique.fr/informatique/Java/1.8/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html), e como o compilador não advinha que você quer, na verdade, configurar apenas os componentes que forem checkbox como selecionado, esse código nem irá compilar. Você precisa primeiro garantir que o componente seja uma instância de `JCheckBox`.

2- mesmo corrigindo conforme mencionado acima, para fazer o cast sem erros, o método [`setSelected()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setSelected-boolean-) recebe um tipo booleano, que representa se ele será marcado(true) ou não(false) e você não está passando nada.

Corrija o laço conforme abaixo:

```
for(int i=0 ; i<box.getComponentCount() ; i++){
    if(box.getComponent(i) instanceof JCheckBox)
   ((JCheckBox)box.getComponent(i)).setSelected(true);
}
```

Recomendo que verifique a documentação da classe/método antes de se aventurar com o componente, pois la mostra para que serve, quais parâmetros recebe e se possui retorno. Os dois erros que citei poderiam ser evitados se a documentação dos respectivos métodos tivesse sido consultada.

Comment: O primeiro erro eu realmente não sabia, mas eu realmente tinha esquecido de colocar o "true", mas eu editei a pergunta e coloquei, então eu conhecia o método setSelected().
Obrigado pela resposta.

Comment: @PedroAfonso mas a recomendação continua válida, é sempre bom consultar a documentação, você acaba aprendendo mais sobre a classe e como ela funciona. A maioria dos problemas costuma ter a resposta lá, facil e rapida. ;)

Comment: Sim, obrigado :)